# I am having a problem in understanding a notation in the book Matrix Analysis by C Meyer.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, problem-solving

I am having a problem in understanding a notation in the book Matrix Analysis by C Meyer.

[image: I have taken a screen shot of the book]

The notation of $A_{*1}$ is where I am facing problem.

Also I want a detail of Reflector....where will I get??

Help Needed!

Answer (score 1):

$A_{\ast j}$ denotes the $j$-th column of $A$ (and we also denote the $i$-th row of $A$ by $A_{i\ast}$). It is a rather popular notation in linear algebra literature.

You may see Wikipedia for accounts of [reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) and [Householder reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation). Alternatively, consult any numerical linear algebra textbook.